# displaying meta key value with wp_page_menu

Tags: menus

I know that WP3 offers wp_nav_menu and description field but I was wondering if it is possible to alter wp_page_menu to echo desired meta key value next to the page link in format that is adjustable.

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to alter the vale of each li in the `wp_page_menu` but there is a way to do it without creating your own function or custom walker using `the_title` filter hook.

so create your function , something like this:

```
function custom_menu_title($title,$post_id){
  return $title . ' ' . get_post_meta($post_id,'meta_key',true);
}
```

and you hook it before you call `wp_page_menu` and remove it right after so:

```
add_filter('the_title','custom_menu_title',10,2);
wp_page_menu(array(...));
remove_filter('the_title','custom_menu_title',10,2);
```

Comment: Will check the solution and answer shortly after. Thanks man.

Comment: How would you display desired meta key value using custom Walker class? No need for whole function just part where you add value to the variable. Thanks